# preg_replace issue with special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to do a preg_replace on some variables. My code is below:

> $message=Welcome, %%name%%!
>
> Congratulations! You are now a member of Expert Online Training (EOT), the world’s best virtual classroom for youth development professionals. By using EOT now, before your job starts at %%campname%%, you will turbocharge your leadership skills, boost your self-confidence, and get even more out of %%campname%%’s on-site training.
>   EOT Logo Take EOT with you. We know you are busy, so our new website is mobile-friendly. You can now watch EOT videos and take your quizzes on any smartphone, tablet, or laptop with a WiFi connection. Imagine learning more about behavior management, leadership, supervision, games, and safety while you sit in a café, library, or student lounge!
>
> %%directorname%% just created an account for you with these login credentials:
>
> %%logininfo%%
>
> To watch EOT’s intro vid and log in, click here.
>
> When is it due? Directors usually require staff to complete their online learning assignment before arriving on-site. If you have not yet received a due-date for your assignment, check with %%directorname%% to get one. As you move through your course, %%directorname%% will have access to an electronic dashboard that allows them to track your progress and quiz scores.

```
  $loginInfo = 'Username: ' . $email . '<br/>'; // Login Information
  $loginInfo .= 'Password: ' . $password;
  $name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
  $campname = get_the_title($org_id); // the camp name
  $vars = array(
      'name' => $name,
      'email' => $email,
      'your_name' => $directorname,
      'logininfo' => $loginInfo,
      'directorname'  =>  $directorname,
      'campname'  =>  $campname,
      'numvideos' =>  NUM_VIDEOS,
  );

  /* Replace %%VARIABLE%% using vars*/
  foreach($vars as $key => $value)
  {
    $message = preg_replace('/%%' . $key . '%%/', $value, $message);
  }
  echo $message; //send message
```

The $email,$password,$first_name,$last_name,$loginInfo,$directorname and $campname are all available in the script. Everything gets replaced correctly except passwords that contain a "$" followed by a number so for example a password like "man$1er" gets replaced to "maner". The "$1" or "$2" in the password gets stripped out. How can I ensure the messages gets replaced with the correct password in case I'm using secure passwords which may contain special characters and numbers like "Ch33tos$1" not beign stripped to "Ch33tos"

Comment: Why do you use preg_replace? There is no pattern, it's only a string replace. You know the exact start word and you have the end word in a variable just str_replace them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you format the question? It looks like `$message`'s string should be in quotes, and in a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no need to even loop the array.
Str_replace accepts arrays.
Add the `%%` at start and end of each key in the array and this code will replace them all.

```
$vars = array(
  '%%name%%' => $name,
  '%%email%%' => $email,
  '%%your_name%%' => $directorname,
  '%%logininfo%%' => $loginInfo,
  '%%directorname%%'  =>  $directorname,
  '%%campname%%'  =>  $campname,
  '%%numvideos%%' =>  NUM_VIDEOS);


$message = str_replace(array_keys($vars) , $vars , $message);
```

See here for a working example https://3v4l.org/T8YGs

---

If you still want to use preg_replace you need to escape the `$` in the string.
See this regex101 for an example, https://regex101.com/r/BRJDCV/1

Answer (score 1):

For something this basic you're better off using str_replace: http://php.net/str_replace

Example:

```
/* Replace %%VARIABLE%% using vars*/
foreach($vars as $key => $value)
{
   $message = str_replace('%%' . $key . '%%', $value, $message);
}
```

This should prevent any issues with special characters in the password.

Please note, your question doesn't specify but if you're sending this message in an email you should **NOT** send a password in an email. Email is not a secure medium.